# PHP imap_search based on message UID

Tags: php, email, imap

Is there any way to search messages on IMAP server, using imap_search function. According to php manual, imap_search allow only limited number of search option, and search by UID is not between them:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php

So, is there a way around, to get messages based on UID(higher then provided UID). This should be supported since IMAP4 protocol revision(i think since year 2003).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure you have gone thru an extensive search and finally landed here. Lets face it, its not possible; but there can be workaround for the feature.

Maybe you can utilise code similar to this:

```
$imap_stream = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password);
$msg_no = 1212; //lets say momentarily
while(imap_fetchheader($imap_stream, $msg_no)){
    //do some processing
    $msg_no++;
}// loop will continue till there is no more of newer messages
```

Be aware that this can cause Maximum Execution Time so you can take in a for loop to do the job with specific number of iteration.

```
$imap_stream = imap_open($mailbox, $username, $password);
$msg_no = 1212; //lets say
for($i=0;$i<=50;$i++){
if(imap_fetchheader($imap_stream, $msg_no)){
    //do some processing
}
$msg_no++;
} // this will go for 50 times
```

Comment: The problem is this code uses message sequence numbers which can change if messages get deleted or moved. So if you store $msg_no as the last message processed, then 5 messages get deleted, you will miss the next 5 messages that arrive. If you're looking to only get messages since the last one, you need to store its UID and then do  `$msg_no = imap_msgno($imap_stream, $lastUID);`

Comment: @CodeBaller yeah that seems better. agreed.